# Is there a time constraint for the Banneret's Bulwark feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, time

The Purple Dragon Knight/Banneret's Bulwark feature at 15th level states:

> Beginning at 15th level, you can extend the benefit of your Indomitable feature to an ally. When you decide to use Indomitable to reroll an Intelligence, a Wisdom, or a Charisma saving throw and you aren’t incapacitated, you can choose one ally within 60 feet of you that also failed its saving throw against the same effect. If that creature can see or hear you, it can reroll its saving throw and must use the new roll.

*(Sword's Coast Adventurer's Guide)*

**If my ally made a save one round ago can it still get a chance to reroll?**

Comment: I really don't like the stylistic changes made in the edit.  I'm not going to rollback myself because that feels too edit-war-y, but if you agree, OP, then a rollback would be appreciated.  The title spellcheck is important, though.

Answer (score 4):

There's a time constraint, but not the one your question suggests.

> **When you decide to use Indomitable** to reroll an Intelligence, a Wisdom, or a Charisma saving throw and you aren't incapacitated, you can choose one ally within 60 feet of you that also failed its saving throw against the same effect. If that creature can see or hear you, it can reroll its saving throw and must use the new roll.

So you can grant a reroll to an ally when you use Indomitable. So when can you use Indomitable?

> Beginning at 9th level, you can reroll a saving throw that you fail.

Note that you reroll a saving throw that you fail, as opposed to your ally, who rerolls a saving throw that they fail**ed**.

So if you fail a saving throw against the effect, you can use Indomitable, and grant a reroll to an ally. For example, if you and your ally are affected by a spell that allows you to make a saving throw every turn, then when you fail yours, you can use Indomitable and let your ally reroll theirs, even though theirs didn't happen at the same time.